# how to iterate over pandas dataframe over multiple column groupBy in python

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset given below:

```
product_name    serial_number     date           sum
"A"             "12"              "2020-01-01"   150         
"B"             "10"              "2020-01-01"   250 
"A"             "12"              "2020-01-02"   350 
"B"             "10"              "2020-01-02"   450 
"A"             "12"              "2020-01-03"   1500 
"B"             "10"              "2020-01-03"   2050
```

I am trying to get subset of pandas dataframe with group of (product_name, serial_number). Here, I have two groups, is there any efficient ways to iterate over groups similar to pseudo code given below in Python:

```
for group_product_name, group_serial_number in data.groupBy():
    //get subset of data with group_product_name, group_serial_number
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
for x , y in df.groupby(['product_name','serial_number']):

     # y is the subset 
     # x is the group name
```